# Subplots using Plotly in R (bug fixed)

Tags: r, plot, datagrid, plotly

How can I create a subplot grid with Plotly in R?

The official site has this [nice Python example](https://plot.ly/python/subplots/):

[image: Python Example]

The python code has the option `rows=2` and `cols=2`, but in R the `subplot` function has just the parameter `nrows`, without `ncols`.

I tried this example in R, but `nrows` do not seam to work as expected:

```
# Basic subplot
library(plotly)
p <- plot_ly(economics, x = date, y = uempmed)
subplot(p,p,p,p,
  margin = 0.05,
  nrows=2
) %>% layout(showlegend = FALSE)
```

They are in a line instead of in a grid. See the result:

[image]

Here is the [R suplots page](https://plot.ly/r/subplots/) for reference. Unfortunately, use `ggplotly` is not a option for me, like [this](https://plot.ly/r/)

### UPDATE

It was a bug. Plotly team is very fast, and it was fixed in just 3 days ([check here](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/313))! Github version is already updated. Great job!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This seems to be a genuine bug in the way `subplot()` generates the y-axis domains for the two plots. Indeed, they overlap which can easily be seen if you execute

```
p <- plot_ly(economics, x = date, y = uempmed)
q <- plot_ly(economics, x = date, y = unemploy)


subplot(p,q, nrows = 2)
```

This will produce the following plot:

[image]

If you take a close look at the y-axis you see that they overlap. That hints at a problem in the way `subplot()` defines the domain of the y-axes of the subplot.

If we correct the domain specification of the y-axes manually (following the [plotly documentation](https://plot.ly/r/reference/#layout-yaxis)), we can solve the problem:

```
subplot(p,q, nrows = 2) %>% layout(yaxis = list(domain = c(0, 0.48)), 
                                   yaxis2 = list(domain = c(0.52, 1)))
```

This produces:
[image]

Now, if you want to reproduce the 4x4 subplot matrix similar to the Python example, you probably need to manually adjust the x-axis domains in a similar way.

Since this is a bug and my solution is only a workaround, I suggest, however, that you file an issue with `plotly` on [GitHub.](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues)

Comment: Tks for your response. I followed you advice and opened the [issue #313](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/313) in GitHub.

Comment: They are really fast. Bug fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://plot.ly/r/subplots/):

```
p <- economics %>%
  tidyr::gather(variable, value, -date) %>%
  transform(id = as.integer(factor(variable))) %>%
  plot_ly(x = ~date, y = ~value, color = ~variable, colors = "Dark2",
          yaxis = ~paste0("y", id)) %>%
  add_lines() %>%
  subplot(nrows = 5, shareX = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: I am trying exactly this example. And I get the error
`Error in subplot(., nrows = 5, shareX = TRUE) : 
  unused arguments (nrows = 5, shareX = TRUE)`