# How to combine pie charts and bar charts in plotly R?

Tags: r, grid, plotly, bar-chart, pie-chart

I want to crate a grid of charts with 1 row and 3 columns, where pie chart to be in 1 and 2 columns and bar chart to be in 3 column.

Here is the code I use:

```
plot_ly(labels = ~Instr,  legendgroup = ~Instr, textinfo = 'label+value+percent', textposition = 'outside') %>%
  add_pie(data = ov_backet_instr, values = ~Volume, domain = list(row = 0, column = 0), hole = 0.6)%>%
  add_pie(data = ov_backet_instr, values = ~Number, domain = list(row = 0, column = 1), hole = 0.6)%>%
  add_bars(data = ov_pivot_instr, x=~Year_month, y=~Number, type='bar', name = ~Instr, text = ~Number, domain = list(row = 0, column = 2))%>%
  layout(title = "Channels", showlegend = T,
         grid=list(rows=1, columns=2),
         xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
         yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
          showlegend = T)
```

However it doesn't work.

How can I modify my code?

Please note that bar chart relies on the other data frame `ov_backet_instr`, than in pie charts `ov_backet_instr`, however the labels are the same in both data frames. And I would like to have the same labels and the same colors accros all graphs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subplots using Plotly in R (bug fixed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33870527/subplots-using-plotly-in-r-bug-fixed)

Comment: @SametSökel unfortunately nope